# How to connect to azure SQL server using visual studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, function, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have an azure function triggered by Cosmos DB. I am getting the data from the JSON file and send it over to my SQL database on Azure.
I wanted to know if I can connect directly to the Azure SQL using my Visual Studio? 
I have connected to it once through the portal, but I can't see that I am connected to my database under **View/Cloud Explorer** in Visual Studio. 
The database is only listed under **View/SQL Server Object Explorer**. I assume this connection is through my local machine, and not directly to the cloud. 
This is my code:

```js
        public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task Run([CosmosDBTrigger(
            databaseName: "ToDoList",
            collectionName: "Items",
            ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosDB",
            LeaseCollectionName = "leases")]IReadOnlyList<Document> input, ILogger log)
        {
            if (input != null && input.Count > 0)
            {
                var cnnString = "Server=tcp:server.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=myDatabase;Persist Security Info=False;User ID={your_username};Password={your_password};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;
                using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(cnnString))
                {
                    sqlConnection.Open();
                    var cmd = new SqlCommand
                    {
                        CommandText = @"insert into [dbo].[Player] ([User],[Timestamp] values(@User,@Timestamp)",
                        CommandType = CommandType.Text,
                        Connection = sqlConnection,
                    };

                    var record = new Record();
                    //set parameters
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@User", record.Email));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Timestamp", record.Timestamp));

                    //Execute command
                    await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                }         
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following steps to **connect to Azure SQL Server using Visual Studio**:

Open Visual Studio and login.

Click on **Open Cloud Explorer to view all subscription to select your subscription**.

[image]

**Select your subscription** => **Select SQL Databases** => **Select your Database** =>**Right Click and select Open SQL Server Object Explorer** => **Enter credentials and connect.**

[image]

After connecting your database => **Right click** => **New Query** => **Enter the query** => On the top of query you will find **available databases (Shift+Alt+PgDn)** and click on **execute (Ctrl+Shift+E)**.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but unfortunately I cant get passed the step after selecting my subscription, because I cant expand that, there is nothing under my subscription unfortunately. I dont understand why. I have my Azure SQL listed under **SQL Server Object Explorer** but cant see it under **Cloud Explorer**

Comment: @SSRH Could you please sign-out and sign-in. After sign-in => Go to View => Select Cloud Explorer => Wait for few seconds and hit on Refresh all.
Can you find you subscription now?

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works now! I should have thought about it. I followed the rest of the steps and I managed it. So now that means I am connected to the server, right? If I can query and see the data from the Azure SQL database.

Comment: Yes, once you have connected to Azure SQL Server using visual studio. You can query directly from visual studio.

Comment: Unfortunately when I run my code, I get this error as a new document enters in to CosmosDB: `Core .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Login failed for user {Admin}` 
Could you have any guess why?

Comment: How I can see the Azure SQL manage instance under Cloud Explore, yes I can see all my Azure SQL server & databases but not able to see the Azure SQL Manage Instance, I am owner of the subscription as well.

Comment: How I can see the Azure SQL manage instance under Cloud Explore, yes I can see all my Azure SQL server & databases but not able to see the Azure SQL Manage Instance, I am owner of the subscription as well.

Comment: Deprecated for VS 2022. Use Connected Services node in Solution Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the Azure SQL Database in Visual Studio Server explorer

[image]

Comment: Thanks but it tells me one or more subscriptions are not supported by Server Explorer, and tells me to open Cloud Explorer. When I open Cloud explorer I see the same thing as I saw before.

Comment: How I can see the Azure SQL manage instance under Cloud Explore, yes I can see all my Azure SQL server & databases but not able to see the Azure SQL Manage Instance, I am owner of the subscription as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** You need to use the following tools to connect Azure Sql Server.

**Which tool should I choose?**

- Do you want to manage a SQL Server instance or database, in a
  light-weight editor on Windows, Linux or Mac? Choose **Azure Data
  Studio**
- Do you want to manage a SQL Server instance or database on Windows
  with full GUI support? Choose **SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)**
- Do you want to create or maintain database code, including compile
  time validation, refactoring and designer support on Windows? Choose
  **SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT)**
- Do you want to query SQL Server with a command-line tool that
  features IntelliSense, syntax high-lighting, and more? Choose
  **mssql-cli**
- Do you want to write T-SQL scripts in a light-weight editor on
  Windows, Linux or Mac? Choose **Visual Studio Code** and the **mssql
  extension**

For more details, refer “[SQL Tools and Utilities for SQL Server, Azure SQL Database, and Azure SQL Data Warehouse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/overview-sql-tools?view=sql-server-2017)”.

Comment: I may have been vague in what I meant, I dont want to manage my SQL at this stage, if I cant write my data to the SQL database, managing it would be pointless since no data is contained in the database. I just need to connect to SQL in Visual Studio to be able to write to the database.