# Where is the database with indivitual accounts in a .NET Core 3.0 Web Application App Service located?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-identity

I'm developing a .NET Core Web application with Microsoft Identity. I've deployed it to the Azure portal as an app service. I need to take a look at the users that I've registered with Microsoft Identity, possibly deleting some of them or modifying, but I don't know where the database is in the cloud. Can anyone help?

Edit: This is the ConfigureServices() method:

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlite(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddIdentityServerJwt();

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();

            services.AddSignalR().AddAzureSignalR(Configuration["SignalRConnectionString"]);

            // In production, the React files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build";
            });

            // For scaffolding:
            services.AddMvc().AddControllersAsServices();

            var task = ConnectToEventHub();
            services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
        }
```

Edit2: I've realized that my problem was that somehow, those users are stored in a database that's stored in a file called app.db. That file resides in the root directory of the web application. Now, this can work, but to make it much more usable to work in a production environment, my boss has asked me to move this database to an Azure SQL Database - or basically the easiest and cheapest database to use against my web application (which is hosted in azure as an app service). Cosmos DB is too expensive to just stored one user table. Anyone got any tips for how to migrate from app.db to something like Azure SQL Database?

Comment: can you share your ConfigureServices() method in Startup.cs?

Comment: can you check connection string in Configuration section of the App Service in Azure Portal? The database should be there

Answer (score 1):

**OLD ANSWER related to Microsoft Identity, not Individual Accounts**

Just look for Azure Active Directory in Azure Portal. You can usually access it trough hamburger menu, or just type Azure Active Directory into the search box:

[image: Azure Portal menu]

In the Azure Active Directory pane, select "Users" from menu in "Manage" section. There are your users.

Alternatively, you might use Azure CLI to query users in the AAD.
Easiest way is to use Cloud Shell directly in Azure Portal, since it is already authenticated against Azure:

[image]

Also, make sure the AAD Tenant ID is the same as the one you use in your app settings.

Your App Service might be deployed to a Azure Subscription that is connected to different AAD.

So for example I can create App Service in my private subscription, but I want to let my company's employees to log in -> I register my app in my company's AAD.

Comment: Thank you but those users are just the people in my company - not the users that I've created for my web application during development time in the Azure cloud.

Comment: Can you describe, how you created the users?

Comment: I used Microsoft Identity scaffolding to create a Register page, which I use to create users. Do you need more info?

Comment: Yes, because Microsoft Identity Scaffolding does not exists as far as I know. :) Did you use Web App template with Authentication with Individual Accounts? Microsoft Identity just a new name for AAD. Maybe you confused it with ASP.NET Identity, which is something else, more general.

Comment: "Did you use Web App template with Authentication with Individual Accounts?". I'm not 100% sure. How can I check and proceed to fix this problem?

Comment: Based on your ConfigureServices, you are not using Microsoft Identity (AAD) at all, but Individual Accounts. So the answer will be completely different :/

Comment: Ok, that could be true, but in any case I need to be able to access these users and know where they are. So does this take us any closer to the resolution?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, based on your Startup class, you are using Individual Accounts (not Microsoft Identity just another name for Azure Active Directory v2).

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
   .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Individual Accounts means that you are using your own database to store users, passwords, roles etc.

---

**When you publish your Web Application to Azure, your local database is not uploaded to Azure.**

If you use Visual Studio to publish, it recognizes that your Web App uses Entity Framework and it can create new Azure SQL Database in the same resource group during the publish. It will have the same structure, however, your local data are not uploaded.

So to answer your question, where is the database - just where you created it during publish or otherwise.

Select SQL Databases in the hamburger menu in Azure Portal and see if you can find the database there

[image: Azure Portal Screenshot]

If not, check your connection string, which you can usually find in Configuration Section of you App Service:
[image: App Service Screenshot]

The connection string will tell you name of the SQL Server and name of the Database, but won't tell you Azure Subscription or Resource Group. It could be theoretically anywhere.

Comment: Thank you once again. But I can see one database under "SQL databases" and I've looked at that database in the Azure Portal before and I just can't see how I can view induvidual tables and in particular the user table. ??

Comment: That is completely different topic, just google "how to connect to azure database" You might use [Query Editor](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/t-sql-query-editor-in-browser-azure-portal) directly in Azure portal, or you might connect to the database using [SQL Server Management Studio](https://adamtheautomator.com/connect-to-azure-sql-database/) or [Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53727420/how-to-connect-to-azure-sql-server-using-visual-studio)

Comment: Thank you. I did that but if I expand the "Tables" tree node in the Query Editor in Azure Portal, there seem to be no tables. Do you know of way to see all the tables somewhere? Something like "select * from tables"? Sorry for all the trouble and thanks for all the help!

Comment: Then in looks like there are no tables and you need to run Entity Framework Migration or [migrate your local database to azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dms/tutorial-sql-server-to-azure-sql). Google how to select all tables using SQL.